# Facing problem with JSON parsing in swift

Tags: swift, codable

My REST returns following Array, and only one item.

```
{
"Table1": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "ClauseNo": "2-111",
        "Title": "Testing Title",
        "URL": "http://www.google.com",
    }
]
}
```

I'm trying to use the Codable as following:

```
struct Clause: Codable {
 var Id: Int
 var ClauseNo: String
 var Title: String
 var URL: String
}
```

What I'm doing wrong with following code?

```
 func parse(json: Data) -> Clause {
 var clause: Clause?

 if let jsonClause = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Clause].self, from:   json) {

   clause = jsonClause
 }

 return clause!
}
```

As I mentioned above, I only have 1 item not more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very common mistake, you are ignoring the root object

```
struct Root : Decodable {   
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case table1 = "Table1" }

    let table1 : [Clause]
}

struct Clause: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case id = "Id", clauseNo = "ClauseNo", title = "Title", url = "URL" }

    let id: Int
    let clauseNo: String
    let title: String
    let url: URL
}
```

...

```
func parse(json: Data) -> Clause? {
    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: json)
        return result.table1.first
    } catch { print(error) }
    return nil
}
```

Side note: Your code crashes reliably if an error occurs

Answer (score -1):

I tend to handle these scenarios like this:

```
struct Table1 : Codable {
    var clauses: [Clause]

    struct Clause: Codable {
        let Id: Int            // variable names should start with a lowercase
        let ClauseNo: String   // letter  :)
        let Title: String
        let URL: String
    }
}
```

And then when you're decoding you end up with a table from which you want the first element, something like:

```
if let jsonTable = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Table1.self, from: json) {
   clause = jsonTable.clauses[0]
}
```

Comment: This won't work. You need to rename the `clauses` property to `Table1` to match the JSON (or use a coding key to map the name).